# Postfix cannot deliver mail to Cyrus mailbox on Ubuntu 11.10 server

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, cyrus

I have installed and configured Postfix and Cyrus IMAP server with webcyradm according to this document - http://www.delouw.ch/linux/Postfix-Cyrus-Web-cyradm-HOWTO/html/index.html .
I can access webcyradm interface, I can create new domains and new users, and I can login via IMAP after creating the user account.

However, Postfix fails to deliver mail to cyrus mailboxes. Mail log contains errors shown below. Installing any IMAP server other than cyrus is not an option because it is needed by the web application. Please advise me how to make Postfix deliver email to cyrus mailboxes. The solution should not necessary include web-cyradm, but there should be a web interface for managing mail domains and mailboxes as user-friendly as possible.

```
Dec 30 22:46:17 acer-tower cyrus/lmtpunix[4865]: accepted connection
Dec 30 22:46:17 acer-tower cyrus/lmtpunix[4865]: lmtp connection preauth'd as postman
Dec 30 22:46:17 acer-tower postfix/cleanup[4868]: 065D5240035: message-id=<20111230214617.065D5240035@home.webshop-software.ch>
Dec 30 22:46:17 acer-tower cyrus/lmtpunix[4865]: verify_user(user.imap0001) failed: Mailbox does not exist
Dec 30 22:46:17 acer-tower postfix/bounce[4867]: 6C6CA24185C: sender non-delivery notification: 065D5240035
Dec 30 22:46:17 acer-tower postfix/qmgr[4833]: 065D5240035: from=<>, size=3372, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 30 22:46:17 acer-tower postfix/qmgr[4833]: 6C6CA24185C: removed
Dec 30 22:46:17 acer-tower postfix/lmtp[4866]: 53421240372: to=<imap0001@home.webshop-software.ch>, orig_to=<someuser@imap.webshop-software.ch>, relay=home.webshop-software.ch[/tmp/lmtp], delay=165, delays=165/0.02/0.17/0.09, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host home.webshop-software.ch[/tmp/lmtp] said: 550-Mailbox unknown.  Either there is no mailbox associated with this 550-name or you do not have authorization to see it. 550 5.1.1 User unknown (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Comment: Question please?!

Answer (score 1):

The user you are mailing to does not exist. See the log entry: `verify_user(user.imap0001) failed: Mailbox does not exist`.

And as you obfuscated the log, one can not be sure that this is the same or a similar error: `550-Mailbox unknown.`

Comment: But the user imap0001 exists in webcyradm and can login via IMAP. I understand that the problem is that cyrus does not see this user, but I don't know how to solve it. I did not obfuscate the log except replacing email address to avoid spam.

Comment: You did not follow the mentioned manual. There is nothing said about configuring cyrus as a lmtp server. But you did and trying to use it. Follow another tutorial with more recent information (and not eight years old).

Comment: Yes, following some more recent guide would be much better. I did not precisely follow that guide exactly because it's too old. But I could not find anything newer. Maybe you have a link or two ?

Comment: No. I can't support the way you do it. Use dovecot! Use dovecot! Use dovecot! Therefore follow this instructions: http://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze